# React method triggered after mounting OR updating

Tags: reactjs

Where should I put my logic which should be run after mounting but also after updating component?

For example If I want to call some api thunk based on received params from redux and/or parent components.

Right now I using this approach, but is it correct or am I missing something?

```js
componentDidMount(){
  this.componentDidUpdate()
}
componentDidUpdate(){
  // the logic (ex: redux-thunk api call)
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? @Melounek

Comment: @PassionInfinite: Like I said, I want to call conditioned api request if the component mounts or if params change

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are doing will have side effect, but I think you should not call react native function like that.

I would do it this way :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._randomFunction();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this._randomFunction();
}

_randomFunction(){
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: I think I would do this if there will be anything I want to do in "update" and not in "mount" function, but it never happend so far (only the opposite case, which is fine)